# 3.3 V and 5 V pins shorted — is the Pi dead?

Tags: rpi.gpio

I am new to Pi development now while working suddenly the cable wires of pin1 (3.3 V) and pin2 (5 V) got in contact for a short time then the Pi shutdown. When I turn it back on, only the LED red is on. The green LED is not, nor is the ACT LED.

I have tried to find a fix but seems that I can't find one—is the Pi dead?

I am using an RPi 3 Model B+.

[image]

Comment: It is dead.  Time to buy a new Pi.

Comment: Aws thanks for your honest answer hurts me but time to move on 

Comment: Same happened to me. The voltage regulator did not output 3v3 after that. Since it is a custom chip, you cannot simply buy and replace it.

Answer (score -1):

It could be the poly fuse also. I was once wiring up a robot and pretty sure i shorted something out on mine. It just died and never came on.. no lights, nothing. Thought it was dead so i left it unplugged and came back to it acouple days later, thought might as well try it and see what happens. Sure enough i plugged it in and it worked like nothing happened.

So just a thought leave it all unplugged for acouple days and plug it back in and see what happens. For some reason several devices i have, have done something similar to this.

Comment: also make a new ISO with pi on it to test it to make sure the sd card that was in the pi when that happened did corrupt it self.

Comment: so there is a possibilities that my raspberry pi can be restored? thanks hope this will work soon how long does it takes?

Comment: Just wait 3-4 days for the poly fuse to restore. You raspberry will work again like Moist Bit said

Comment: Connecting the 5V pin to the 3V3 pin is not going to draw enough current for the polyfuse to operate.  No point in giving false hope.

Comment: I just want to know if I need to buy a new one or wait the polyfuse to reset?

Comment: @SnowAngel , like joan is saying, connecting the 5V pin to the 3V3 pin  most likely wouldn't use enough power to activate the polyfuse, which means you will probably have to buy a new pi.